# Upsell on WooCommerce Thank You Page using Cross-selling products

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to make an up-sell section on the `Thank You` page using the `cross-sell` products of the products in the order. The code that I am using works fine IF and only IF all products have cross-selling products. **Example:** if under `Linked Products` there are no `Cross-Sells` added, the code won't work.

The same thing happens if the customer buys one product without cross-selling products and one with. The code only works if all products in the order has cross-selling products.

This is the error I get, which I cannot figure out:

```
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in /wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 84
```

**And this:**

```
Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 84
```

I've tried back and forth getting this to work with and without cross-selling products. Basically, I need it to not show anything if there are no cross-sell products and if there are, show the section. The customer should obviously be able to buy one or more products without cross-sell products added to them and one or more that has and then - based on that, still see the up-sell section.

I hope this make sense (getting confused myself).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'upsell_on_thankyou', 3 ); 
function upsell_on_thankyou( $order_id ){

    $cross_ids = array();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $cross_ids = array_unique( array_merge( get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_crosssell_ids', true ), $cross_ids )) ;
    }

    if( !empty( $cross_ids ) ) :

        $upsell_cross = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => array( 'product', 'product_variation' ),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post__in' => $cross_ids,
            'orderby' => 'post__in'
        ) );

        if( $upsell_cross->have_posts() ) :
            echo '<section class="upsell-cross-products"><h2>Present for you!</h2><div class="woocommerce columns-3">';

            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            while ( $upsell_cross->have_posts() ) : $upsell_cross->the_post();


                $product = wc_get_product( $upsell_cross->post->ID );

                if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
                    continue;
                }

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            endwhile;

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

            woocommerce_reset_loop();
            wp_reset_postdata();

            echo '</div></section>';
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

I'm drawing a blank as to what I'm doing wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following get_post_meta doesn't necessarily returns a list of products:

```
get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_crosssell_ids', true )
```

If it's empty, it won't return anything. And I actually not sure how it returns array if it has a value, since you ask for single value by setting the third param to `true`. anyway,

You first need to prepare before the array merge:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$product_crosssell_ids = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_crosssell_ids', true );

if (is_array($product_crosssell_ids) && !empty($product_crosssell_ids)){
$cross_ids = array_unique( array_merge( $product_crosssell_ids, $cross_ids )) ;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this. your example does not work either and it throws an error:

`Warning: Use of undefined constant product_crosssell_ids - assumed 'product_crosssell_ids' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 84`

If you have any other ideas, please share them.

Comment: right. sorry, forgot the $ sign. Still, I did not tested it, but please try.

Comment: gosh, that's embarrassing :) Yep, seem to work fine now. Thank you! Very kind.